# How to convert jpg array [255 255 204 114... to tensorflow image array [0. 0. 0.03921569 0.47450984

Tags: tensorflow

I am using jpeg image the output number is as following

```
    255 255 227 119   3 140 251 240 243 243 245 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 254 255 240 128  97  79  52   5   0   0  23  13
   14  15  16  14  90 248 254 254
```

but i found tensorflow MNIST's numbering is something like

```
0.          0.          0.02352941  0.50980395  0.94117653  0.99607849
  0.90196085  0.66666669  0.13333334  0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.
```

So i suspect the evaluation fail is because of the numbering format.

Following is my code from jpg image to evaluation.

```
fp = open("2.jpg","rb")
img = Image.open(fp).resize((28, 28), Image.ANTIALIAS).convert('L')
pic = numpy.asarray(img)
pic = numpy.resize(pic,(1,784))
images = pic
labels = [mnist.test.labels[119]] # 2
print("Own test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: images, y_: labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rescale the input:

```
  pic = pic/255.
```

Comment: Yes it able to translate to below 1 value `[[ 1.          1.         0.99607843 ` but still fail to evaluate

Comment: What error do you get? and how is the accuracy node defined?

Comment: No error. Just not evaluation wrong only. But the image preparation code here is working for my own images https://niektemme.com/2016/02/21/tensorflow-handwriting/